# Exporting Google suite users from group API app scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

First post ever, Looking to get some help here. I'm trying to run a daily job using googles apps scripts. I essentially want to export all groups within my google apps/suite domain (im a super admin) and list the users within them then have that data imported into a google sheet. Here's what I have so far. The documentation gives me a headache. Any help would be appreciated.

I've already done the initial steps to authorize

```
function readgroupsandusers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {

//Pulls down Admin SDK API that allows auth.
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'example@.com',

//Show max result of 500.
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });

//Presents group name + group email address.
    var groups = page.groups;
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];     
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', group.name, group.email);
        var users 
//I know something is suppose to go here...
      }

    }
    else 

//If it doesn't find anything present this message.
    {     
      Logger.log('No Groups in this domain exist.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: What's happening when you run this? Is the script in a spreadsheet? More information about what's happening would be helpful.

Comment: @BrianBennett HI! - When I run the above I get a list of all groups within my domain. The script currently is running behind google app scripts. I'm stuck at trying to extract each user within each of their respective groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AdminDirectory.Members.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list), to list all the members of a group.

```
members = AdminDirectory.Members.list({
      groupKey: group.id
    });
```

Hope this helps.